# Tachyons as vector representations on the surfaces transitivity of Lorentz group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, faster-than-light, causality, tachyon

In Wikipedia's [surfaces of transitivity (of Lorentz group $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Surfaces_of_transitivity), it says

> "Standard vectors on the **one-sheeted hyperbolas** would correspond to tachyons. Particles on the light cone are photons, and more hypothetically, gravitons. The "particle" corresponding to the origin is the vacuum."

By definition of the Lorentz group, it preserves the quadratic form
$$Q(x) = x_0^2 - x_1^2 - x_2^2 - x_3^2$$
of the Minkowski space.

According to [surfaces of transitivity (of Lorentz group $G$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Surfaces_of_transitivity):
If a group $G$ acts on a space $V$, then a surface $S  ⊂  V$ is a  surface of transitivity if $S$ is invariant under $G$, i.e., $∀ g  ∈ G$, $∀s  ∈  S :  gs  ∈  S$, and for any two points $ s_1 ,  s_2  ∈  S$ there is a $g  ∈ G$ such that $gs_1  = s_2$.

I thought

- tachyons are **time-like**, instead of **space-like**.
- $Q(x) < 0$ is a **hyperboloid of one sheet**. Points on this sheet are **space-like** separated from the origin.
- $Q(x) > 0, x_0  > 0$ is the upper branch of a **hyperboloid of two sheets**. Points on this sheet are separated from the origin by a future  time-like  vector. $Q(x) > 0, x_0 < 0$ is the lower branch of this hyperboloid. Points on this sheet are the past  time-like  vectors.

If my understanding is correct, then Wiki's "Standard vectors on the one-sheeted hyperbolas would correspond to tachyons" is wrong, but "Standard vectors on the two-sheeted hyperbolas would correspond to tachyons."

> => Is the statement in Wikipedia incorrect? Am I correct or incorrect?

Comment: I edited my post for clarity - let me know if you can approve to upvote my question. if you down vote please let me know why.

Comment: I also adjusted the title to "Tachyons as vector representations on the surfaces transitivity of Lorentz group?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tachyons are **time-like**, instead of **space-like**.

[Tachyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon#Tachyons_in_relativity) are "faster than light particles",
and, thus, have **space-like** 4-momentums (one is shown as the red segment below),
which point outside of the light-cone.
Constant-magnitude tachyon 4-momenta have their tips lying on the hyperboloid of one sheet (for example, on the red hyperbola below) when the diagram is expanded to include the suppressed spatial dimensions.
(Timelike vectors have tips in the blue-shaded region.)

In the diagram below, time $t$ runs along the vertical axis (Desmos's $y$-axis).

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ceo1eymwqx
[image: robphy-tachyon-hyperbola]